# iTunes Search API get 0 results at c# programm but 1 result at Chrome browser

Tags: c#, itunes, itunes-search-api

I created a C# programm which searches movie details with the title of the movie.
I create the link:

```
        string link = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?";

        link += "term=";

        string cTitle = Titel.Replace(" ", "+");
        link += cTitle;

        link += "&country=DE";
        link += "&media=movie";
        link += "&entity=movie";
        link += "&attribute=movieTerm";
        link += "&limit=1";
```

with the movie title "Bus 657" that would be the following link:

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Bus+657&country=DE&media=movie&entity=movie&attribute=movieTerm&limit=1

If I open that link I get a txt file with the result I need. But if I get that in c# with the following code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var json = client.DownloadString(link);
Thread.Sleep(3100);
```

I get  0 results.
Can someone help me to fix that?

I have a lot movie titles which title are named by the original iTunes title of the store at germany.

Thx :)

Comment: That text file contains zero results.

Comment: With the link I posted? My text file shows 1 result

Comment: `{ "resultCount":0,  "results": [] }`

Comment: I get that file: {
 "resultCount":1,
 "results": [
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"feature-movie", "trackId":1059063782, "artistName":"Scott Mann", "trackName":"Bus 657", "trackCensoredName":"Bus 657", (...) ]

Comment: i get a result from the link - {
 "resultCount":1,
 "results": [
{"

Comment: i tried the link too and it does give me one result (i am located in Germany). Could it be some itunes API logic using client (browser) information? I don't know how WebClient identifies itself to the webserver, compared to a regular browser. Maybe check both requests with fiddler and add needed headers to your WebClient request.

Comment: I only get at some titles no result, I worked with 780 titles and 700 had a result and 80 not. and the Bus 657 is one of them. And I named it like the title you see at iTunes

Comment: `Titel.Replace(" ", "+");` should be replaced with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the User Agent to the request header and try.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
var json = client.DownloadString(link);
```

I received `"resultCount":1`

Comment: That worked for the Bus 657 problem, but the other movies have no results

Comment: @MMbach Can you share another title you're facing issue with?

Comment: I think the title is correct, I have the same problem for other titles

Comment: This link works too: `https://itunes.apple.com/de/search?term=bus+657&media=movie&entity=movie&attribute=movieTerm&limit=1`. I removed the country from QueryString. Try this and see if it works for other movie titles. 

Also use lowercase **de** instead of DE.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is wrong.

You have:

```
                                        BZZZZT - should be %20
                                        ↓
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Bus+657&country=DE&media=movie&entity=movie&attribute=movieTerm&limit=1
```

Your movie title is "Bus 657".  That space should be encoded as `%20`, not a `+`.  Your link should be:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Bus%20657&country=DE&media=movie&entity=movie&attribute=movieTerm&limit=1
```

With the corrected link, you get results.  You should be using [`HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or some other function to properly URL encode your URL.  Or build your URL using the [`UriBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) class.

Comment: So I tried it with the new code:
string cTitle = Titel.Replace(" ", "%20");
But that doesnt worked for that one.

Comment: Have you a good tutorial how to build that with URI for my case?

Comment: No, find one using Google.